# Java - Scanner throws a NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

In my program I have a method for choosing a account from text file. But when compilator gets to the line where user enter his choice it throw a exception `NoSuchElementException`: No line found. Please help me.

```
private int chooseAcc() throws IOException {
    int choice = -1;
    int numOfLine = 0;
    do {
        if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                while (br.readLine() != null) {
                    numOfLine++;
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the option: ");
        try {
            choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()); //stack trace error here
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        if (choice < 0 || choice > numOfLine) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    } while (choice < 0 || choice > numOfLine && numOfLine == 0);
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `sc` ?

Comment: How do you define your sc in sc.nextLine()? Where does that sc come from?

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: What was the input that cause the nosuchelementexception ?

Comment: Declared for the whole class

Comment: I did input nothing

Comment: Can you tell me how to reproduce ? Because `sc.nextLine()` should be blocking, and whatever i input, i only get NumberFormatException, no nosuchelementexceptions...

Comment: I dont know what do you mean. When I'm debuging my program all is OK but when compilator gets to this line it redirect to 

**private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) { 
      getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e); 
}**

After that it throw nosuchelementexception.